# bash - нахождение файлов-сценариев и нахождение наиболее часто используемого интерпретатора

Tags: bash

Есть задание: 
Найти в директории /bin все файлы, которые являются сценариями, и вывести на экран полное имя файла с интерпретатором, наиболее часто используемым в этих сценариях (только полное имя файла).

Вопрос в том, как мне определить, является ли файл сценарием и как определить наиболее часто используемый интерпретатор для этих сценариев?

Comment: Разбирайте вывод `file /bin/* | grep script | awk '{ print $2 " "  $3 }' | sort`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> как мне определить, является ли файл сценарием

воспользуйтесь программой [*file*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/file.html). пример:

```
$ file /bin/which
/bin/which: POSIX shell script, ASCII text executable
$ file /bin/zsh5
/bin/zsh5: Paul Falstad's zsh script, ASCII text executable
```

> как определить наиболее часто используемый интерпретатор для этих сценариев?

просто посчитать [*шебанги*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3_(Unix)). например, так:

```
file /bin/* | grep ' script' | cut -d : -f 1 | xargs -n 1 head -n 1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn
     22 #!/bin/sh
      1 #!/bin/zsh -f
      1 #! /bin/sh
```

Comment: А если ещё научиться пользоваться sed...